# how to call vue i18n from non vue class?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui, vue-i18n

I am using the [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html#named-formatting) for a vuejs app.

All good, except how can I access the translations from a class that is not an extension of vue. Below is a simple class containing [validation methods](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form#custom-validation-rules) for element-ui to use eg:

```
import Validate from '@/services/Validate';

class FormValidate {
  public password(rule: any, value: string, callback: any) {
    callback(Validate.password(value) ? undefined : new Error('errors.passwordInvalid'));
  }
}

export default new FormValidate();
```

Above the Error "errors.passwordInvalid" is a key for the translation file.

Within a typical component `$t('errors.passwordInvalid')` will return the human friendly string in the correct language.

How can i access the translation lib from this isolated class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a thread on vue i18n github [there](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/149#issuecomment-472278674) or [there](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/149#issuecomment-357455921). Basically the answer seems to be that you should separate i18n related code from your `main.js` file into `i18n.js` file. Which could look like:

```js
export default new VueI18n({
    // with all your settings here
})
```

Then import it as pure js file and `t()` method should work everywhere.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Worked like a charm! `i18n.tc('errors.nameInvalid')` after importing worked:  https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/149#issuecomment-357455921